# How can a MySQL query return several records from a single row?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that include 3 fields (among others) that for each of them that is equal to 1 I need the query to return a record.
So, if all 3 fields are equal to 1 the query should give 3 records.
If two fields (any of the three) are equal to 1 the query should return 2 records and so on.

How would a query like that look?

Comment: why would you want to do this? fetch the single row and go from there. why go to the extra work of hacking together an UGLY query to make 3 rows from one, then having to do 3 fetches, when you could run ONE query with ONE fetch.

Comment: This is why - for an example, I need to get the five first fields which are equal to 1, and only them.    If there was just one field like this in every row than I would just simply use LIMIT.    But, as it is the first five can be located in two rows but they can also be spread through 5 different rows. So how can I know where to stop the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE field1=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * from table WHERE field2=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * from table WHERE field3=1
```

The logic is that we select the rows we need for each criteria one by one, and then create an union of them. It is true however, that this does not scale nice... Then again, I have never ever faced this requirement "out in the wild"...